# How can I get host system information Like ip ,cpu utilization etc by edge module or edge service

Tags: java, docker, azure-iot-edge

I have a requirement of getting system information like ip,cpu utilization, etc.
I want to send this information to my backend by using azure iot edge device.
Currently, I have created a java jar which can get host information and by providing the module connection string in it, It can send data to iot hub.
But in my requirement, I can not provide a connection string of module so I want to create a module which can create a connection by the environment.
For doing this I have to create a docker image of the module and then deploy it on edge host.
But I am unable to get host information inside the docker container.
So what should I do for this requirement?

Comment: Depending on the how your java jar is implemented, you might be able to get it to work from inside side the container by running it in privileged mode and/or bind mounting some host resources into the container.

Comment: How can we  provide the privilege to our jar for getting this type of information